# Htaccess redirection, redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I would like to redirect `mysite.com/index.php` to `mysite.com/index.php?id_category=12&controller=category`

Here is my htaccess file.

But it doesn't work. Chrome says : `This webpage has a redirect loop`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule index\.php http://mysite.com/index.php?id_category=12&controller=category
```

Comment: Why `mysite.com/index.php`? You are not passing parameters in the entered URL so there is no need to enter `index.php`. `mysite.com` is enough. ¿Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?foo=bar [R=301,L]
```

The first condition checks if the URI is equal to `index.php` and the second one checks if GET values are empty. The AND between the 2 conditions is implicit here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should change use another file name instead of index.php for the destiny. But you can try:

RewriteRule index.php index.php?id_category=12&controller=category